# Ruby on Rails embedded ruby generating errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am working my way through Ruby on Rails 2nd Ed., Hartl. In section 3.3.3 my tests failed after I removed some static text with some embedded Ruby. The test was passing previously no problem.

rspec

```
    require 'spec_helper'

    describe "Home pages" do

      describe "Home page" do
        it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
          visit '/static_pages/home'
          page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
        end

        it "should have the title 'Home'" do
          visit '/static_pages/home'
          page.should have_selector('title', :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample                 App | Home")
        end  
      end
    end
```

home.html.erb

```
    <% provide (:title, 'Home') %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <h1>Sample App</h1>
          <p>
             This is the home page for the
             <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
             sample application.
          </p>
       </body>
    </html>
```

error from console

```
    C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rspec         spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
    ?[31mF?[0m?[31mF?[0m?[32m.?[0m?[32m.?[0m?[32m.?[0m?[32m.?[0m

    Failures:

      1) Home pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
         ?[31mFailure/Error:?[0m ?[31mvisit '/static_pages/home'?[0m
         ?[31mActionView::Template::Error:?[0m
           ?        [31mC:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1: syntax         error,
     unexpected ',', expecting ')'?[0m
           ?[31m...putBuffer.new; provide (:title, ' Home') ?[0m
           ?[31m...                               ^?[0m
           ?        [31mC:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1: syntax         error,
     unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end?[0m
           ?[31m....new; provide (:title, ' Home') ?[0m
           ?[31m...                               ^?[0m
    ?[36m     # <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'?[0m
    ?[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top         (required)>'?[0m

      2) Home pages Home page should have the title 'Home'
         ?[31mFailure/Error:?[0m ?[31mvisit '/static_pages/home'?[0m
         ?[31mActionView::Template::Error:?[0m
           ?        [31mC:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1: syntax         error,
     unexpected ',', expecting ')'?[0m
           ?[31m...putBuffer.new; provide (:title, ' Home') ?[0m
           ?[31m...                               ^?[0m
           ?        [31mC:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:1: syntax         error,
     unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end?[0m
           ?[31m....new; provide (:title, ' Home') ?[0m
           ?[31m...                               ^?[0m
    ?[36m     # <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'?[0m
    ?[36m     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top         (required)>'?[0m

    Finished in 0.51562 seconds
    ?[31m6 examples, 2 failures?[0m

    Failed examples:

    ?[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:6?[0m ?[36m# Home pages Home page         should have the h1 'Sample App'?[0m
    ?[31mrspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11?[0m ?[36m# Home pages Home page         should have the title 'Home'?[0m
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove the whitespace prior to the parenthesis

```
provide (:title, 'Home')
```

should be

```
provide(:title, 'Home')
```

Comment: Its working now. It was the whitespace. Thanks. I knew it had to be something simple, just couldn't see it. Good job muttonlamb!

Comment: Just as an FYI for the future, Ruby can get a bit finicky about parentheses.  You can leave a whitespace when omitting parentheses (obviously), but sometimes it will get confused if you leave it between a method call and the parentheses.  This doesn't apply everywhere though, so it's best to be consistent and ensure you don't leave a space before parentheses